# Download email list from custom database on wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an admin panel from my functions.php (of the my customized theme) and there i created some pages. One of them is the email list.

I would like to export the saved data (on a custom database table) but i cant as long i cant put header on my page because there was already sent header befose the wordpress opens my page.

Any idea on how i could download the saved emails stores from my database?

Im on a page added like this:

```
add_theme_page( 'Newsletter', 'Emails Nota 10', 'manage_options', 'emails.php', 'paginaEmails');
```

The page is like that

```
function paginaEmails()
{

    if ( (isset($_GET['exportar'])) and ($_GET['exportar']='true')){
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tb_emails_newsletter';
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("select * from " . $table_name);
        var_dump($result);
        if (count($result)>0){
            //just a test
            header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="teste.csv";'); 
        }
        echo '';exit;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="section panel">
    <h1>Emails Cadastrados</h1>
    <a href="?page=emails.php&exportar=true">Exportar Emails CSV</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to set up your own endpoint for this via the Rest API functionality, and then make your link trigger that, instead of loading the same page again with an extra parameter. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: Thats a great idea. I will take a look on that. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CBroe i have found a solution. Here it is:

Generated a link like: admin-ajax.php?action=baixarEmailCSV on my page (working on functions.php)

At that page i put this code:

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce("baixarEmailCSV_nonce");
```

Then, the baixarEmailCSV function (also in functions.php)

```
function baixarEmailCSV() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tb_emails_newsletter';
    $lista      = $wpdb->get_results("select * from " . $table_name);
    gerarArquivoCSV($lista, 'emails.csv');
}
```

And finally the function that sends the CSV header:

```
function gerarArquivoCSV($results, $name = NULL)
{
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file_name.csv');
    //write data into CSV
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    //convert data to UTF-8 
    fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    foreach ($results as $line) {
        echo $line->tx_email.';'.$line->tx_pagina .';
        ';
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Thanks again and i hope it helps somebody else!